# transpose column to row - python

Tags: python-3.x

How can I transpose the ouput of many rows to one row which is comma separated?

```
with open(filein, 'r') as rh:
    for line in rh:
        clm = line.split(',')[0] #Returns first column
        print(clm)
```

Current Output - Many Rows:

```
abc
def
ghi
jkl
```

Desired Output - One Row, Comma Separated:

```
abc,def,ghi,jkl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python 2.x, to suppress the automatic newline of print, add a trailing `,` (comma). Now a space will be used instead of a newline.

```
with open(filein, 'r') as rh:
    for line in rh:
        clm = line.split(',')[0] #Returns first column
        print clm, ',',
```

In python 3.x, add end=' ' argument:

```
with open(filein, 'r') as rh:
    for line in rh:
        clm = line.split(',')[0] #Returns first column
        print(clm, end=',')
```